# RedirectRule for Directory

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having some trouble with Htaccess and RewriteRule.
Basically:
I have a directory called /_dev/WEBDEV and want people to access it from /WEBDEV on the server. 
(http://domain.com/WEBDEV will point to http://domain.com/_dev/WEBDEV)

Here is the htaccess code I have used

```
RewriteRule ^WEBDEV(|/)$ /_dev/WEBDEV/
RewriteRule ^example(|/)$ /_dev/example/
```

So when i go to http://domain.com/WEBDEV, the page shows, but there is no CSS styling or images.
What i mean:

```
<img src="img/shape3.png">
```

the url on the server would be  /_dev/WEBDEV/img/shape3.png
but with the Htaccess it gives

```
http://domain.com/img/shape3.png
```

as the image (and throws a 404).

Plus, i have a file on my server /_dev/WEBDEV/app1.php and with the htaccess it gives a 404 not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define your RewriteBase correctly

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Your rewrite rule should not be triggered if the requested url matches a file or directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And you'll need to add the rule's REGEXP match to the rewritten path
But first, rewrite the path to the WEBDEV directory so it always have a slash after it

```
RewriteRule ^WEBDEV$ WEBDEV/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^WEBDEV(.*)$ /_dev/WEBDEV$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^example(.*)$ /_dev/example$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is quite like creating aliases, but it can be done in `.htaccess`

For external resources like css and html, you just have to change their paths to

```
<img src="/img/shape3.png">
```

for example. This way the absolute path is calculated from the domain name (or base path), resulting in `yourdomain.ext/img/shape3.png` which should work.

Comment: What should i use? I dont want to basically say that if they enter WEBDEV or WEBDEV/ in the browser the url changes to /_dev/WEBDEV/

Should i use Base Href or ?

Comment: I might just put all css, image and js files in /assets/ on the root directory.
But the problem will still be that it will still throw a 404 for app1.php

Comment: Right ok, so the edited code does work, but it works for the URL with a trailing slash, without it, it gets redirected to the actual url.

Comment: Just add RewriteRule ^WEBDEV$ WEBDEV/ [L,QSA] first

Comment: That messed up the page which was working, since it now says that they are from the root of the domain, which they arent at all.

Comment: Well I think that's kind of a different question. You may wanna rewrite the paths with the WEBDEV folder prefix, thus not exposing the real images path...